# what does levelling mean here?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I'm quite puzzled by the word "levelling" in the following sentences. What does it mean in the following sentence?

> Above all, there is something about the curious business of chewing and swallowing together that is **levelling**; it is easier to work out if you like someone when eating than when eyeball to eyeball in an interview room. [source](https://www.ft.com/content/a049213a-dc79-11e5-a72f-1e7744c66818)

Comment: heres a better source, and the comment is in the last 15 seconds of the podcast, btw: https://www.ft.com/content/651976f6-431e-4498-9d14-83dcf7600b77

Answer (score 1):

The link is behind a paywall.
"Levelling" probably means that people are put on the same level, as opposed to one being a superior and one being an inferior.
It's easier to decide whether you like someone when engaged in an activity that is shared between humans as equals.